# RubyAMF and Rails 2.3.3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amf

Is anyone else seeing unpredictable results using Flex 3 with Rails 2.3.3 and RubyAMF 1.6.5?

I had to revert back to Rails 2.3.2.  Anyone have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nevermind...I found a few issues with name-spacing in my code.  Once fixed, RubyAMF 1.6.5 worked fine with Rails 2.3.3.

After further exploration, I see to have run into the issue again.  Looks like RubyAMF is choking on a serialization.  Any clues on how/what to dig deeper into this issue?

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!

You might have expected an instance of Array.

The error occurred while evaluating nil.include?

/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:142:in `create_time_zone_conversion_attribute?'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:75:in `define_attribute_methods'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:71:in `define_attribute_methods'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:242:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/base.rb:2826:in `hash'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:221:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_proxy.rb:221:in `method_missing'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/associations/association_collection.rb:370:in `method_missing'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:366:in `[]='
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:366:in `store_object'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:260:in `write_amf3_array'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:151:in `write_amf3'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:242:in `write_amf3_object'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:236:in `each'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:236:in `write_amf3_object'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:154:in `write_amf3'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:78:in `write'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:70:in `run'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:56:in `upto'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/io/amf_serializer.rb:56:in `run'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/app/filters.rb:91:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:10:in `realtime'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/app/filters.rb:91:in `run'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/app/filters.rb:12:in `run'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/app/filters.rb:11:in `each'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/app/filters.rb:11:in `run'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/vendor/plugins/rubyamf/app/rails_gateway.rb:28:in `service'
/Users/los/working/test-repo/msnmgmt-backend/app/controllers/rubyamf_controller.rb:16:in `gateway'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1327:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:1327:in `perform_action_without_filters'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:617:in `call_filters'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:610:in `perform_action_without_benchmark'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:10:in `realtime'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activesupport-2.3.3/lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:17:in `ms'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/benchmarking.rb:68:in `perform_action_without_rescue'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/rescue.rb:160:in `perform_action_without_flash'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/flash.rb:146:in `perform_action'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:527:in `send'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:527:in `process_without_filters'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/filters.rb:606:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:391:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/base.rb:386:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/routing/route_set.rb:434:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:88:in `dispatch'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:111:in `_call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:82:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:29:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/query_cache.rb:34:in `cache'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:9:in `cache'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:28:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/activerecord-2.3.3/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:361:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/head.rb:9:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:24:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/params_parser.rb:15:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/session/cookie_store.rb:93:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/reloader.rb:29:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/failsafe.rb:26:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `synchronize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/lock.rb:11:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/actionpack-2.3.3/lib/action_controller/dispatcher.rb:106:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/rails/rack/static.rb:31:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:46:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/urlmap.rb:40:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:17:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/content_length.rb:13:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/chunked.rb:15:in `call'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:61:in `process'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:159:in `process_client'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `each'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:158:in `process_client'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:285:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `initialize'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `new'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mongrel-1.1.5/lib/mongrel.rb:268:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.0.0/lib/rack/handler/mongrel.rb:34:in `run'
/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-2.3.3/lib/commands/server.rb:111
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `gem_original_require'
/Library/Ruby/Site/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:31:in `require'
script/server:3
```